# JavaScript Updating a dictionary from array of values using array of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a dictionary (nested), an array of keys, and an array of values. I need to update the dictionary with the given values using the array of keys as the address. Example:

```
dict = {"a":{"b":[{"c":1,"d":2},{"c":3,"d":4}]}}  
address = [["a","b",0,"c"],["a","b",1,"d"]]  
value = [10,40]
```

The desired output is:

```
dict = {"a":{"b":[{"c":10,"d":2},{"c":3,"d":40}]}}
```

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: How did you do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a function for setting the value and reduce the path to the inner property.

```js
function setValue(object, [...keys], value) {
    var last = keys.pop();
    keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k], object)[last] = value;
}

var dict = { a: { b: [{ c: 1, d: 2 }, { c: 3, d: 4 }] } },
    address = [["a", "b", 0, "c"], ["a", "b", 1, "d"]],
    value = [10, 40],
    i,
    l = address.length;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) setValue(dict, address[i], value[i]);

console.log(dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines:

```js
const dict    = {"a":{"b":[{"c":1,"d":2},{"c":3,"d":4}]}},
      address = [["a","b",0,"c"],["a","b",1,"d"]],
      value   = [10,40];

// For each address
address.forEach((path, index) => {
  let el = dict;
  // For each address fragment
  for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    // If it's not the last fragment
    if (i < path.length - 1) {
      // Navigate to the next
      el = el[ path[i] ];
    } else {
      // Otherwise, set the value
      el[ path[i] ] = value[index];
    }
  }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(dict));
```